# Online service for localization applications (Launchpad.net alternative)

Tags: gettext

I'm looking for service like http://translations.launchpad.net for localization my app into different languages (based on the gettext) with a team work support.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here are a few](http://www.google.com/squared/table/agKatmw8erZ9ap-tZdrsqYKQ)

- Transifex is used for the Fedora project
- Damned lies is for GNOME
- Pootle is for OpenOffice.org
- (Vertimus was for gnomefr, but has been merged into/superseded by Damned lies)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Transifex - is just what I need.

Comment: Alas, the link is broken. (Google Squared)

Comment: @Evan Yeah, and I didn't get warned in advance, now it's lost to me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a new one - http://lokali.se, supports various file formats, collaborators, placeholder validation and other stuff.